# Display html tags on htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, html

I've been making a chat for my friends and I, I wanted it to be secure so I put a htmlspecialchars when displaying the messages, but take a look at the code:

```
    while($message = $getMess->fetch())
    {
        $words = array('lmao', 'angry');
        $emojis = array(
            '<img src="/image/emoji/emoji.png" width="15px" height="15px" alt="lmao" />',
            '<img src="/image/emoji/angry.png" width="15px" height="15px" />');

        $msg = str_replace($words, $emojis, $message['message']);

        echo htmlspecialchars($message['username']) . ' ' . trim(htmlspecialchars($msg));
    }
```

So when I want an image to be displayed, it does not work because I use a htmlspecialchars function.

I want to know how could I make the images appear but not any other html tags ? 
(its my first question, don't be aggressive :c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is change the order of `str_replace` and `htmlspecialchars`

so you would first escape the input of user and then before outputing replacing the tags with the html code (that you know is safe since you prepared it yourself in the array)

```
$msg = htmlspecialchars($message['username']) . ' ' . trim(htmlspecialchars($message['message']));

echo str_replace($words, $emojis, $msg);
```

This will also do the replacement in the username if someones username contains "the smiley string".

If you need to prevent that i would suggest the following code:

```
$safeUsername = htmlspecialchars($message['username']);
$safeMsg = trim(htmlspecialchars($message['message']));
echo $safeUsername . ' ' . str_replace($words, $emojis, $safeMsg);
```